# Generate ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have been reading a few topics but couldnt find a solution to this one I am stuck on.

I am trying to add **ng-model** inside **ng-repeat** something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="list in lists">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.checkboxes.{{ list.value }}"> {{ list.number }} {{ list.description }} <br/>
</span>
```

and the list values are like this:

```
$scope.lists = [

    {

        value:'value1',
        number: '1',
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ',    
    },

    {
        value:'value2',
        number: '2',
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ', 
        },

        {
        value:'value3',
        number: '3',
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ',            },
    ];
```

Inside the ng-repeat loop, I want it to build a ng-model like: `formData.checkboxes.value1 formData.checkboxes.value2, formData.checkboxes.value3` etc..

Is this possible? When I try the above method nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should define `formData.checkboxes` model inside your controller like this:

```
$scope.formData = {
    checkboxes: {}
};
```

... and the you can populate it like that:

```
<span ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.checkboxes[list.value]"/> 
             {{ list.value }} {{ list.number }} {{ list.description }} <br/>
</span>
```

Please take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LX2Cn/) for working example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
<span ng-repeat="list in lists">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.checkboxes[list.value]"> {{ list.number }} {{ list.description }} <br/>
</span>
```

Comment: yeah that works. And like @PrimosK pointed out, I need to define `formData.checkboxes` model inside my controller first. Thanks for your support. :)