# Assigning ng-model to checkboxes generated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have set up a json containing a list of countries with an ID and Country code attached:

It looks like this:

```
$scope.countries = [
  {"name":"Afghanistan","id":"AFG","country-code":"004"},
  {"name":"Åland Islands","id":"ALA","country-code":"248"},
  {"name":"Albania","id":"ALB","country-code":"008"},
  {"name":"Algeria","id":"DZA","country-code":"012"}
]
```

I then use the `ng-repeat` directive to create checkbox inputs for every country.

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
      <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{country.id}}" ng-true-value="'{{country.name}}'" ng-false-value="''">{{country.name}}</label>
</div>
```

However when I run the code I only get the following to display:

Location
checkbox here `{{country.name}}`

If I remove the `ng-model` part of the repeat my checkboxes generate fine but I need a unique `ng-model` to be attached to every checkbox

```
ng-model="{{country.id}}"
```

How would I go about attaching a unique `ng-model` value?

This answer ([Generate ng-model inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387326/generate-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat)) does not provide a unique `ng-model` value

Comment: Try removing the `{{}}` around the `{{country.id}}`

Comment: When I do this I get the same ng-model value for all checkboxes but I need a unique ng-model value for every checkbox

Comment: Try setting `ng-repeat` to `country in countries track by $index` and `ng-model` to `countries[$index]`

Comment: This also seems to only give me the same ng-model for all checkboxes - ng-model="countries[$index]"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I will suggest you, **use:**

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCountry.selected[country.id]" ng-true-value="'{{country.name}}'" ng-false-value="''">{{country.name}}</label>
</div>

{{myCountry.selected}}

JS:

$scope.myCountry = {
    selected:{}
};
```

Comment: This is what I thought would work but for some reason I still get the same ng-model value for every repeat of my checkbox. I'm getting myCountry.selected[country.id] for every checbox

Comment: I guess, you are checking it by inspecting element. It will show same. Pass model to controller and console the result. you will get your answer.

Comment: Oh you are right. I was using inspect element. Thanks for helping

Comment: works for me. But how to iterate  through myCountry.selected?

Comment: @AnushreeAcharjee what problem you faced? Iteration is easy correct?

Comment: Can you let me know your concerns?