# Angularjs with dynamic model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this working piece of code that is repeated multiple times.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in test{{c}}.collection">
      {{ item.hwTypeName }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and below is the code in controller for this

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.searchParameters = {userName: '', userEmail: ''};

    var c=123;

   var test="test"+c



  $scope[test].collection = [{"ticketHardwareId":3817987,"requestId":3854951,"hwId":64543,"hwPrice":0,"assetId":"98ifgh","hwTypeName":"HW Type-1"}]


}
```

But this is not working,what could be the issues please help

Fiddle Link :http://jsfiddle.net/sLqpL29b/1/

Comment: follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917218/assigning-ng-model-to-checkboxes-generated-by-ng-repeat/27917524#27917524

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your fiddle. The setup is not complete.

See my updated fiddle, if this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/4jbjmwve/

Anything that you binding to view should be defined on `$scope`