# how to get both checkbox value and radio value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

hi this is [MY PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/R4mdZr/)

there is a condition in my json is it"s min value of the ingredients is equal to one means it will change to radio and if it"s greater than  one means will change to checkbox ..

**to show it as radio**

```
 ng-if="get_ingredientTypeName_values.minVal == 1"

<input id="{{get_option_names_price.ingredientTypeId}}_{{$index}}" name="{{get_option_names_price.ingredientTypeId}}" type="radio">
```

**to show it as checkbox**

```
ng-if="get_ingredientTypeName_values.minVal == null">
  <input id="{{get_option_names_price.ingredientTypeId}}_{{$index}}" name="{{get_option_names_price.ingredientTypeId}}" type="checkbox">
```

how to get both values and save to an array ?

Comment: Which are these both values you mention?

Comment: want to save both radio button values and checkbox values to an array

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: On a side note, I believe you should have a different `id` for these two different elements. And for fetching the value, a `ng-model` seems a good way to go?

Comment: OK can you explain it in a fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've updated your plunker to a working example](https://embed.plnkr.co/QDSaSi/)

Let me guide you through what was necessary to fix your problem. If have put the list of ingredients that can be selected into a directive for easy scaling and readability.

The first thing that needed to be done was make sure that single values are rendered as a radio button and multiple values as a checkbox. For this I do the same check as you did:

```
// Check if the ingredients should be displayed as a radio button or a checkbox
scope.inputType = scope.ingredientType.minVal == 1 ? "radio" : "checkbox";
```

This allowed me to render the ingredients either as a radio button or checkbox with the following template (ignore the `ng-checked` and `ng-click` for now):

```
<ul class="col-xs-12 form-group" ng-repeat="get_option_names_price in ingredientType.ingredientList ">
  <li><input type="{{ inputType }}" ng-checked="valueIsSelected(get_option_names_price)" value="{{ get_option_names_price.productId }}" ng-click="toggleSelection(get_option_names_price)">{{get_option_names_price.ingredientName}}, $ {{get_option_names_price.ingredientPrice}}</li>
</ul>
```

The next step is keeping track of the selection in code. This is quite tricky because in case of a radio button we can simply use `ng-model` but for supporting checkboxes as well, we need to keep track of the selection in the code. For this I introduced a property on the ingredient to an empty array and I've added a function to the directive that is triggered by clicking the radio button or checkbox (this is why the template contains an `ng-click`):

```
// Set the initial selection value. Because we need to have the possibility to select multiple values, this is an array
scope.ingredientType.selection = [];

// Function that is triggered by clicking an ingredient. The clicked item is passed to the function.
// If multiple values are allowed, a check is being made whether the item was already selected. This means we should remove it from the selection.
// If only one value is allowed, a single value array is set as the selection of the control.
scope.toggleSelection = function(clickedItem){
  var value = clickedItem.ingredientName;

  // Multiple values are allowed
  if(scope.inputType === "checkbox"){
    // Check if the clicked item exists in the selection
    var index = scope.ingredientType.selection.indexOf(value);

    // It doesn't exist
    if(index === -1){
      scope.ingredientType.selection.push(value);
    } else {
      // It already exists, so it should be removed
      scope.ingredientType.selection.splice(index, 1);
    }
  } else {
    // Only one value is allowed
    scope.ingredientType.selection = [value];
  }
}
```

Finally, we need to make sure that the selected values are presented to the user so he knows what he selected. This can be achieved by using the `ng-check` directive and making a call to a function in our own directive controller:

```
// Function that checks whether an item is selected. 
// This function is being used in the template to show the user whether he has selected an item or not.
// -> ng-checked
scope.valueIsSelected = function(item){
  var value = item.ingredientName;

  // Check if the clicked item exists in the selection
  var index = scope.ingredientType.selection.indexOf(value);

  return index > -1;
}
```

Because we added a property to the ingredient, this can be accessed through the entire angular application and there's no need to have a button that collects the selected items.

Comment: exactly  this is i wanted but how to push all the the values (i.e) if i clicked small then corresponding values `{
                        "_id": "584aa4e218c5b62c02b6fe6a",
                        "productId": "584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67",
                        "ingredientTypeId": "5822f17b24baa627770af5ed",
                        "ingredientName": "small",
                        "slug": "small",
                        "isActive": true,
                        "ingredientPrice": -75
                    }` are of pushed to the array .. can we do it ? ..

Comment: can you show as normal instead of using it as a directive

Comment: Hi @User_3535, sorry for my late response but I've been very busy. Why would you want to avoid using directives? Directives and components are all about scalability and reusability. Avoiding them only makes you need to do some extra checks on value availability and so on.